# Serial monitor returning unintelligible characters arduino

Tags: arduino

I added LEDs turning on to my sketch which read temperature sensor values, and now my serial monitor returns garbage y characters. I have an array that initializes and controls the LEDs. Could the problem be with my loops that initialize and turn off the LEDs? Thanks.

```
const int temperaturePin = 0;

int leds[] = {13, 12, 11};

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i--) {
        pinMode(leds[i], OUTPUT);
    }
}

void loop(){
  // Multiple declarations on one line
    float voltage, degreesC, degreesF;

  // Measure true voltage with custom function
    voltage = getVoltage(temperaturePin);

  // Convert voltage to degrees Celsius
  // This line compensates for an offset of .5
  // in the TMP36 temperature sensor
    degreesC = (voltage - 0.5) * 100.0;

  // Convert Celsius to Fahrenheit
    degreesF = degreesC * (9.0/5.0) + 32.0;
    Serial.print("Voltage: ");
    Serial.print(voltage);
    Serial.print(" Deg C: ");
    Serial.print(degreesC);
    Serial.print(" Deg F: ");
    Serial.println(degreesF);
    if ((degreesF >= 75) && (degreesF <= 76)) {
        digitalWrite(leds[0], HIGH);
    }
    else if ((degreesF >= 77) && (degreesF <= 78)) {
        digitalWrite(leds[1], HIGH);
    }
    else if ((degreesF >= 79) && (degreesF <= 80)) {
        digitalWrite(leds[2], HIGH);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        digitalWrite(leds[i], LOW);
    }

    delay(1000);
}

float getVoltage(int pin){
    return (analogRead(pin) * 0.004882814);
}
```

Comment: You are probably not printing in the right format: http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Print

Comment: In `for` loop in `setup` you should increment, not decrement `i`.

Comment: Thank you! I changed the way my for loop works, so I must have missed that when I was fixing it up.